# Python: name variables with a loop

Tags: python, variables, loops

for our ansys software i would like to generate a script to automate certain things.
when i record my actions I get the following

```
template1 = GetTemplate(
    TemplateName="Random Vibration",
    Solver="ANSYS")
system1 = GetSystem(Name="Modal (ANSYS)")
component1 = system1.GetComponent(Name="Engineering Data")
component2 = system1.GetComponent(Name="Geometry")
component3 = system1.GetComponent(Name="Model")
component4 = system1.GetComponent(Name="Solution")
componentTemplate1 = GetComponentTemplate(Name="SimulationSetupCellTemplate_StructuralRandomVibrationANSYS")
system2 = template1.CreateSystem(
    ComponentsToShare=[component1, component2, component3],
    DataTransferFrom=[Set(FromComponent=component4, TransferName=None, ToComponentTemplate=componentTemplate1)],
    Position="Right",
    RelativeTo=system1)
```

there need to be created 72 sytems, so i would like to do this with a loop in stead of manually copy paste these. What is the best way to proceed

Comment: Please rephrase your question with an example of the data and the code. Where is the datastructure you're trying to scan?

Comment: the code is an ansys dataset, but this is not relevant since the scanning itself goes without problem. it is the creation of the copied systems. Every new block is a copy paste of the previous one - system2, system3, ..., system72

Comment: this is what i had so far for the copy loop or                      i in range (2, 38):
   B=i-1
   "system"+str(i) = template1.CreateSystem(
   ComponentsToShare=[component1, component2, component3],
   DataTransferFrom=[Set(FromComponent=component4, TransferName=None, ToComponentTemplate=componentTemplate1)],
   Position="right",
   RelativeTo="system"+str(B))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully undesrtood your question but from your code naming I think this is what you want:

```
systems1 = []
systems2 = []
templates = []
components1 = []
components2 = []
components3 = []
components4 = []
for i in range(72):    
    template = GetTemplate(
        TemplateName="Random Vibration",
        Solver="ANSYS")
    system = GetSystem(Name="Modal (ANSYS)")
    component = system.GetComponent(Name="Engineering Data")
    component1 = system.GetComponent(Name="Geometry")
    component2 = system.GetComponent(Name="Model")
    component3 = system.GetComponent(Name="Solution")
    componentTemplate = GetComponentTemplate(Name="SimulationSetupCellTemplate_StructuralRandomVibrationANSYS")
    system = template.CreateSystem(
    ComponentsToShare=[component1, component2, component3],
    DataTransferFrom=[Set(FromComponent=component4, TransferName=None, ToComponentTemplate=componentTemplate)],
    Position="Right",
    RelativeTo=system)
    templates.append(template)
    ... rest of appends...
```

The appends are if you need to access those later as I guess you do. If you actually need them to be named system1, system2 etc you could use `exec` and build your strings in a loop.